# How do I check what item in a dictionary is a variable in python?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, input

```
cheats = {
            "GODMODE" : "Health and armour + 1000",
            "Full pockets" : "adds 1000 of each item",
            }
commands = {
             "cheats" : "show cheats",
             "activate [cheat]" : "activates a cheat",
             }
command = input(">").split()
if len(command) == 0:
    continue

if len(command) > 0 :
    verb = command[0].lower()

if len(command) >1 :
    item = command[1].lower()

if user_input = "activate" :
    if item in cheats:
```

How do I check what cheat the user wants to activate? Everything else works.It is part of a bigger part of code.

Comment: What is `item` in your code? Is `item` something you get from another user input?

Comment: Your code contains many mistakes...for example: use `==` instead of `=` and your `item` is never defined

Comment: item is the thing they input after activate. It does work try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pull the relevant value from the dictionary or `None` if it doesn't exist.

This assumes that you don't want to do anything unless you get input in the form of: `activate cheatcode`

```
cheats = {
        "GODMODE" : "Health and armour + 1000",
        "Full pockets" : "adds 1000 of each item",
        }
ask  = input("what do you wish to do?")
code = ask.split()[1]
activate = cheats.get(code,None)
#do something based on activate value
```

Activate now has the value of the cheat selected or `None`. No need for loops or conditionals unless you want to allow enabling multiple cheats at once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `cheats.keys()`. It returns a tuple of the dictionary's keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `try...except` block:

```
if user_input == 'activate':
   try: 
       activate(cheats[item])   # or whatever
   except KeyError:
       print("bad cheat")
```

Comment: `activate(cheats[item])` doesn't work at all and is a syntax error.

Comment: @user7695144 It's just pseudocode.  I assume there's a function `activate`.  That's what I was trying to indicate with the comment.